# ValueError: Unsafe header value

Tags: python, post, http-headers, tornado

I have developed a quite big web application using Tornado 4.2. One of the handlers of my application is responsible for verifying the login details of the user through a post request.

Specifically in this handler I use signed cookies with [set_secure_cookie](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_secure_cookie) to identify the logged in users and their permissions, using the below code:

```
self.set_cookie("user", self.get_argument("username"), domain=".my-domain.com", expires_days=None, httpOnly=True) 
self.set_secure_cookie("access", str(data['permissions']), expires_days=None, httpOnly=True)
```

After setting the cookies I use Tornado's [redirect](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.redirect) to send the user to another URL.

```
self.redirect("/"+lang+"/base_fx.html")
```

On most cases it works as expected without any issue. However, for some users I get the below error.

```
       self.redirect("/"+lang+"/base_fx.html")   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 671, in redirect
        self.finish()   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 934, in finish
        self.flush(include_footers=True)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 884, in flush
        self.add_header("Set-Cookie", cookie.OutputString(None))   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 339, in add_header
        self._headers.add(name, self._convert_header_value(value))   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 369, in
    _convert_header_value
        raise ValueError("Unsafe header value %r", value) 
ValueError: ('Unsafe header value %r', 'access="2|1:0|10:1485161516|6:access|3892:eydvd…<long string>..f0a2f8ad"; httponly; Path=/') 
ERROR:tornado.general:Cannot send error response after headers written
```

Has anyone came across a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Georg Jung post pointed me to the right direction. The issue,*ValueError: Unsafe header value*, I have faced is related to two existing raised issues: [1473](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/1473) and [1025](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/1025) which have now been solved on the [4.3](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/releases/tag/v4.3.0) version of Tornado. The issue for me was that some usernames were lengthier than some other resulting the header size for these usernames to be greater than 4000.

So to properly solve this issue you can take one of the two actions below:

1. Update your Tornado to a version equal or greater than 4.3.
2. Or if you do not want to upgrade it, you can increase the limit of the header size to be 8000 or more. You can do that by changing the file **web.py** in the installed distribution of Tornado in your system.

For example on a Debian system the path is:

```
usr/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/tornado/web.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [corresponding source code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.2.0/tornado/web.py#L367) gives two options:

1. There is an invalid character in your cookie value. This could only be in the username as the `set_secure_cookie` method correctly escapes it's given value as base64. Please ensure that your username does not contain [invalid characters](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.2.0/tornado/web.py#L350) (`[\x00-\x1f]`) or - far better - use a secure cookie for the username too.
2. In my opinion the more likely reason this happens is that your permissions object is to big for putting it in a cookie. Tornado limits cookie values to a length of 4000 (see [source](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.2.0/tornado/web.py#L367)). When using a secure cookie there is more information than your data that needs to fit in plus your data is encoded as base64, which makes it even bigger. Storing such big information as a cookie might not be a good idea for many reasons (i.e. its send with every request, ...). You should either save that data server-side or use a different local sotrage technology than cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Georg! So the issue is that I haven't checked the source for my installed version but for the newest. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I have up-voted and  posted the solution for this :)